# Filtering result of regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I got a big text with a parenthesis and some text inside that needs parsing.

I successfully use this regex `(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\(.*)`, to catch everything inside the parenthesis but the I need do another regex inside the result and this fails.

My code:

```
import re

txt = "COM: (ZZZ, Min: 2, Max: 114)\n"
txt+= "TESTING : BBB"
m = re.match(r'(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\(.*)', txt)

comm = str(m.group(2)).strip()
print(comm) #  Output: (ZZZ, Min: 2, Max: 114)

trk = re.match(r"\bMin", comm)
print(trk) # Output: None, should be "Min"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Barmar this is not the same like the question you suggested, If I comment out all the previous code and all that is left is the last regex again I get no result.

Comment: All you have to do is change the second `re.match` to `re.search`.

Comment: The other question explains that `re.match` only matches at the beginning. You're getting `None` because `Min` is not at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Barmar like this: trk = re.match(r"\bMin", '(ZZZ, Min: 2, Max: 114)')
I get None again. So the problem might be on the regex

Comment: You're still using the wrong function!

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176299/discussion-between-antonis-and-barmar).